# Python: How to match value of a list inside a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes three parameter (one of them is a json.file, don't worry bout this one) and returns the reaction that will happen if the patient takes a specified match. But I'm having trouble telling Python to do so. I feel like my approach using loop is wrong here, as I want the parameters to search for the right fit and produce the answer of output[][2]

```
output=[['Tom', 'Bee', 'Hives'],
 ['Bean', 'Ivy', 'Bruising'],
 ['Tom', 'Shellfish', 'Itching']]

def reaction(json_file, patient, substance):
    for allergies in output:
        for allergy in allergies:
            if patient == allergy[0] and substance == allergy[1]:
                result = allergy[2]
            else:
                return None
            
            return result


assert reaction(ALLERGIES_FILE, 'Tom', 'Bee') == 'Hives'
assert reaction(ALLERGIES_FILE, 'Tom', 'Shellfish') == 'Itching'
```

Comment: you have a return result inside the inner loop. That will make both loops iterate only once.

Comment: I attempted it, but it doesn't work. I feel like my approach using loop is wrong here, as I want the parameters to search for the right fit and produce the answer of output[][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your function like this,

```
def reaction(patient, substance):
    result = None
    for allergies in output:
        if patient == allergies[0] and substance == allergies[1]:
                return allergies[2]
    return result
```

When `return` on the else part the function will return `None` in the first iteration. And you are iterating over sublist of `output` which is unnecessary.

Also, `json_file` is not being used in your method.

Execution:

```
In [1]: reaction('Tom', 'Bee')
Out[1]: 'Hives'

In [2]: reaction('Bean', 'Ivy')
Out[2]: 'Bruising'
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I see!. So I have to return at the start otherwise it will only loop just once.